# WordPress users in Datatables with shorting , searching and paginate

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datatable

I am making a plugin to display all user info in a [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) but i am failed to implement Search, filter and Pagination . I have about **20k** users. Please help me.

may be I need to change my query to join `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` and get the result for my case. I have fount a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198602/inner-join-4-table-in-datatables-server-side) and a similar [tutorial here](http://learninfinity.info/demo/server-side-processing-datatable-with-php-mysql/) . I am not good in writing MySQL query. Please help me with this.

I get ajax response like

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 1,
  "recordsFiltered": 1,
  "data": [
    [
      "example@mail.com",
      "Some Name",
      "",
      "admin",
      ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

**This is my table structure**

```
 <table id="user_table" class="display table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="user-table">
            <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Name </th>
            <th>Url</th>
            <th>nickname</th>
            <th>description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).on('load', function () {
      setTimeout(loadtable, 200);
    });
    function loadtable(){
        var ajaxurl =  USERAjax.wpajaxusersearch;
        var dataTable = $('#user_table').DataTable({  
           "processing":true,  
           "serverSide": true,  
           "order":[],  
           "pageLength": 10,
           "ajax":{  
                url: ajaxurl,  
                type:"POST"         
           },   
      });
    }
});
```

also added localize script like

```
function users_assets_scripts(){

    wp_register_script( 'jquery_datatables_js',  plugins_url( 'asset/js/datatables.min.js' , __FILE__ ), array(),null,true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_datatables_js' );

    wp_register_style( 'jquery_datatables_css',  plugins_url( 'asset/css/datatables.min.css' , __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery_datatables_css' );

    wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'USERAjax', array('wpajaxusersearch' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=wpajaxusersearch' )) );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'users_assets_scripts');
```

and my data fetching function with ajax response

```
<?php 
function wpajaxusersearch(){ 

    $request=$_REQUEST;

    global $wpdb;
    $sort= "user_registered";

    //Build the custom database query to fetch all user IDs
    $all_users_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $wpdb->users.ID FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY $sort ASC LIMIT ".$request['start'].",".$request['length']." " );

    $totalData=$wpdb->num_rows;

    $data=array();
    foreach ( $all_users_id as $i_users_id ) {

            $user = get_userdata( $i_users_id->ID);

            $email              =$user->user_email;
            $user_fullname      =$user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
            $user_url           =$user->user_url;
            $user_nickname      =$user->nickname;
            $user_profile       =$user->description;
                $sub_array = array();  
                    $sub_array[] = $email;  
                    $sub_array[] = $user_fullname;  
                    $sub_array[] = $user_url;  
                    $sub_array[] = $user_nickname;   
                    $sub_array[] = $user_profile;    
               $data[] = $sub_array; 
    }

    $json_data=array(
        "draw"              =>  (isset($request["draw"]) ? $request["draw"] : 0),  
        "recordsTotal"      =>  intval($totalData),
        "recordsFiltered"   =>  intval($totalData),
        "data"              =>  $data
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);
    wp_die(); //to remove that 0 response
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpajaxusersearch', 'wpajaxusersearch' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpajaxusersearch', 'wpajaxusersearch' );
```

Comment: Why are you using AJAX here? Will not DataTables itself handles pagination as well as search?

Comment: habdle but it load time slow and load all data or I have no idea ? can you  help me on this? or any better idea? but I need live filter

Comment: What is the issue with your code? Is it returning just single data?

Comment: its just load the data only what selected on drop down. but search and filter is not working

Comment: I can't understand, can you share your URL here?

Comment: URL shared on our previous discussion section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these to your theme's 'functions.php' and everything should be fine.

```
// change user query to treat meta result as OR part
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'user_meta_OR_search');
function user_meta_OR_search($q){   
    if ($search = $q->get('_meta_or_search')){
        add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', function( $sql ) use ( $search ){
            global $wpdb;

            // run once
            static $nr = 0; 
            if( 0 != $nr++ ) return $sql;

            // modify WHERE
            $where = sprintf(
                " AND ( %s OR %s OR %s ) ",
                $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->users}.user_email like '%%%s%%'", $search),
                $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->users}.user_url like '%%%s%%'", $search),
                mb_substr( $sql['where'], 5, mb_strlen( $sql['where'] ) )
            );

            $sql['where'] = $where;

            return $sql;
        });
    }
}

function wpajaxusersearch()
{               
    $request = $_REQUEST;
    $columns = array('user_email','first_name','user_url','nickname','description');
    $search = esc_attr( trim( $request['search']['value'] ) );

    $args = array();
    $limit_args = array( 'number' => $request['length'], 'offset' => $request['start'] );   
    $order_args = array();
    $search_args = array();

    if ( isset($request['order']) && count($request['order']) )     
    {
        $sort_column = $request['order'][0]['column'];          
        $sort_column_name = $columns[$sort_column];
        $sort_dir = $request['order'][0]['dir'];

        if( stristr( $sort_column_name,'user_' ))
            $order_args = array( 'orderby' => $sort_column_name, 'order' => $sort_dir );                
        else
            $order_args = array( 'meta_key' => $sort_column_name, 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => $sort_dir );
    }
    else
        $order_args = array( 'orderby' => 'user_registered', 'order' => 'ASC' );

    $args = $order_args;

    if(isset($search) && $search != "") 
    {
        $search_args = array(               
            '_meta_or_search' => "*{$search}*",    
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'first_name',
                    'value'   => $search,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'last_name',
                    'value'   => $search,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'nickname',
                    'value'   => $search,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'description',
                    'value'   => $search,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );                          
    }       

    $all_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    $total_users = count($all_users->get_results());
    $filtered_users = count($all_users->get_results());

    if(isset($search) && $search != "") 
    {
        $args = array_merge($args, $search_args);
        $all_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
        $filtered_users = count($all_users->get_results());
    }

    $args = array_merge($args, $limit_args);
    $all_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );        

    foreach ( $all_users->get_results() as $user ) {
        $email = $user->user_email;
        $user_fullname = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
        $user_url = $user->user_url;
        $user_nickname = $user->nickname;
        $user_profile = $user->description;
        $sub_data = array();  
        $sub_data[] = $email;  
        $sub_data[] = $user_fullname;  
        $sub_data[] = $user_url;  
        $sub_data[] = $user_nickname;   
        $sub_data[] = $user_profile;    
        $data[] = $sub_data; 
    }

    $json_data=array(
        "draw"              =>  (isset($request["draw"]) ? $request["draw"] : 0),  
        "recordsTotal"      =>  intval($total_users),
        "recordsFiltered"   =>  intval($filtered_users),
        "data"              =>  $data
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpajaxusersearch', 'wpajaxusersearch' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpajaxusersearch', 'wpajaxusersearch' );
```

Comment: yes search is working and shorting for example if clock on table hear they should be shot like order

Comment: Search is not working also the order is not showing from all data but it order the corrent page data

Comment: I just checked and search working fine. Yes, the sort will sort the current page results alone due to WordPress `usermeta` table constraints.

Comment: I'll try more and get back to you regarding whole records sorting possibility.

Comment: Copy both the functions to your 'functions.php' and everything should work fine. I revamped the full code to achieve sorting.

Comment: Glad to see my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178492/26350) was somewhat helpful here :-)

Comment: This example works very fine with less number of users . I said I have 20k user bro  and it not loading :(

Comment: Seems you have changed few columns and you need to alter the code accordingly.

Comment: Can you post the updated code in your question (since I am not sure about the meta keys you have used)?

Comment: Bro I need your help to fix search search query I need to setup old version because your new version is slow to search [code] https://codeshare.io/G6gWZQ

Comment: Okay, let me check, just the loading time alone issue for you?

Comment: Also, can you post the URL in our last discussion?

Comment: you mean want to see live data ?

Comment: added it on top of that code share url you can check. I cannot directly share it here :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181458/discussion-between-outsource-wordpress-and-firefog).